# Error 'No Living connections' while using ElasticSearch API

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

Using ElasticSearch API in node.js, after installing dependency and run the node.js app cause the below error.

```
Elasticsearch ERROR: 2017-04-11T04:40:01Z
  Error: Request error, retrying
  POST http://localhost:9200/reports/report/_search?size=5000000 => connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9200
      at Log.error (/home/kartik/Documents/Project/Validus/validus_reports_server/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/log.js:225:56)
      at checkRespForFailure (/home/kartik/Documents/Project/Validus/validus_reports_server/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/transport.js:240:18)
      at HttpConnector.<anonymous> (/home/kartik/Documents/Project/Validus/validus_reports_server/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/connectors/http.js:162:7)
      at ClientRequest.wrapper (/home/kartik/Documents/Project/Validus/validus_reports_server/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:4968:19)
      at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
      at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:169:7)
      at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:258:9)
      at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
      at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
      at emitErrorNT (net.js:1256:8)

{ [Error: No Living connections]
  message: 'No Living connections',
  body: undefined,
  status: undefined }
```

Help me to solve this

Comment: Any Progress on this?

Comment: I too am facing the exact same issue. Any solutions yet?

Comment: Just Try in not intel processor systems. Like amd

Comment: I face this issue occasionally, and it seems random. I can't find any issues with in kibana monitoring (resource wise). Sometimes this happens under low-load, sometimes it doesn't happen under high load. Even when running identical queries on unchanged data sets. (Stack Version 6.3.2)

Comment: No solution for this yet?